# SSRS "total" expression in some rows

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

[image]
With SSRS how can I modify this table so the last "Line Amount" value with a repeated "Invoice Number" gets modified with the diference between "LineAmount" total and "Invoice Amount Total".

In the example, the SUM of all Line Amount values is 1574,47

I want the last value (22,77) to be **439,54**, which is

`Invoice Amount total - SUM(Line Amount)
 2014,01 - 1574,47`

And this should be done with evert block that had a repeated "Invoice Number".

Is this possible?

If there's a way to do it directly with SQL Server (which I think its even more complicated) would be ok too.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your tablix with a row group grouping on the Invoice Number, you can add a "total" row before or after the individual line item entries. You can do this by right clicking on the row group, then Add Total, then select before or after (in your case, you would want after). In the new row, you can then create an expression in the column where you would like to see the difference.

You wouldn't be able to have this *replace* the last row (at least not to my knowledge), so you would still have 22,77 showing. But it should get you closer to what you're looking for.

I'm not sure exactly how your dataset is structured, so your exact expression for the difference might be slightly different than this example. If the Invoice Amount is only contained on one row for that invoice number, then your expression would just look something like this:

```
=SUM(Fields!InvoiceAmount.Value) - SUM(Fields!LineAmount.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot add another row, that's why I need to modify the last one. I saw that there's a Previous function, that can look up for the previous value, but that doesnt complety do the work. A Next funcions would be perfect, but it's not available =(

Comment: Why can you not add a new row to the report as @Piston suggested? It's only the report design that's changing, not the data.

Comment: Because I need a clean table to import to Excel, that will be read afterwards to import to another database.